# Nodejs Express, обработчик формы в отдельном файле

Tags: node.js, post, express

Собственное есть некоторая форма в файле.

```html
<form action="/form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Она обрабатывается в app.js

```js
app.post('/form', function(req, res, next){
    код обработки формы, заносит данные в БД
});
```

У меня все работает хорошо. Нужно код обработки формы вынести из app.js в отдельный файл. Если обработок форм будет 20, файл app.js будет огромен с точки зрения количества строк.
Не ругайте, я только изучаю node.js.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вынести в модуль.

```
module.exports.formHandler = function(req, res, next) {

};
```

А в app.js делать

```
var handlers = require('module-name');

app.post('/form', handlers.formHandler);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за помощь.